# Triggering button event (or atleast appear to) via keyboard press AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

Attempting to make a piano in AS3 and so far I have 2 methods of triggering a note, 1 via keyboard and 1 via mouse-click. When I click the key, it changes colour to indicate that the key has been pressed. Unfortunately , I can't find a way for the keyboard event to trigger the button press, is it possible and how would I do it?

It doesn't need to be an actual button press, it can instead just appear to be.

*EDIT*
The button is a button object, using the GotoAndStop causes the following error code:

"project.as, Line 13, Column 7  1061: Call to a possibly undefined method gotoAndStop through a reference with static type flash.display:SimpleButton."

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to extract the piano key press logic into its own function, and then call that function from two events.

```
function pressedMyPianoKey(){
   // Do something like pianoKey.gotoAndStop(2) to show a new graphic
}

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDown);
function keyDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void 
{ 
    pressedMyPianoKey();
} 

pianoKey.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, click);
function click(e:MouseEvent){
    pressedMyPianoKey();
}
```